# ERROR :gpu_process_transportfactory.cc(1`017) Lost UI shared context with NON headless chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, runtime-error

I'm trying to run some UI tests using Selenium 3.14 with IDE IntelliJ. They are being run on a VM o/s Linux 3.10.0 64 bit and I'm trying to run them against Chrome version 67.0.3396.99
when I run them the browser opens but the page doesn't load and I get the message above and `ERROR:sandox_linux.cc(378) InitializeSandbox()` called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

I've found both these errors discussed here but each time the question includes that Chrome is being run headlessly and I'm running non headlessley
I've tried setting various flags `--no-sandbox, --disable-gpu` but nothing seems to work

I've tried opening Chrome from the command line and the same thing happens.

Comment: As I've stated in my question the answers you point to refer to the users attempting to specifically run headless Chrome I am running Chrome non headlessly

Comment: Irrespective of running `headlessley`or `non-headlessley`, as you are using _linux_ OS, the argument **`--disable-gpu`** is not a valid argument. Please check the dup marked discussions carefully.

Comment: I've run the code both with and without --disable-gpu with the same result. I've read the discussions and  tried all the suggestions  (as one suggested the argument I added it)  with no impact so I'm wondering if there is anything else that anyone can suggest I try

Comment: You need to update the question with your _research efforts_, _code trials_ and _error trace logs_ to demonstrate how your question is different from the dup marked question.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've tried so many variations over the last few weeks based on various solutions suggested At first I tried with no arguments other than -- password-store-basic , --log-level-ALL and --port=8080 (as I need to connect to a specific port)

Comment: I began to see the error. I then did a search and found the question you mention above. Reading that the issue should not occur as I was using os Linux and not running a headless version of Chrome. Idid more investigation and found that the issue did affect Linux at some time. SO I tried the --disable -gpu and --disable-software-rasterizer but still got the error. I've removed the arguments and the error still occurs I cannot find an example of a solution for this error on a Linux Box so I have raised this